# How to add robots.txt to my WordPress site?

Tags: wordpress, web-crawlers, robots.txt

How to add `robots.txt` to my [wordpress.com](https://wordpress.com/) site?

Answer (score 1):

WordPress.com comes with a `robots.txt` file already installed, and does not allow you to edit it directly. However, if you edit your blog's [privacy settings](https://en.support.wordpress.com/settings/privacy-settings/), your `robots.txt` will update itself accordingly.

A setting of `public` gives this `robots.txt` file:

```
# If you are regularly crawling WordPress.com sites, please use our firehose to receive real-time push updates instead.
# Please see https://developer.wordpress.com/docs/firehose/ for more details.

Sitemap: https://example.wordpress.com/sitemap.xml
Sitemap: https://example.wordpress.com/news-sitemap.xml

User-agent: *
Disallow: /wp-admin/
Allow: /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php
Disallow: /wp-login.php
Disallow: /wp-signup.php
Disallow: /press-this.php
Disallow: /remote-login.php
Disallow: /activate/
Disallow: /cgi-bin/
Disallow: /mshots/v1/
Disallow: /next/
Disallow: /public.api/

# This file was generated on Thu, 13 Dec 2018 19:12:49 +0000
```

And a setting of `hidden` or `private` gives this `robots.txt` file:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /

# This file was generated on Thu, 13 Dec 2018 19:13:08 +0000
```

Comment: I did stumble across [this blog article](https://vip.wordpress.com/documentation/robots-txt/) that appears to show how you can _modify_ `robots.txt` (on `wordpress.com`) by "hook[ing] into the `do_robotstxt` action, or filter the output by hooking into `robots_txt`"?

Comment: @MrWhite That's for "Wordpress VIP" - an enterprise product. I think it's safe to assume that the asker isn't using the enterprise version or they would have mentioned it. But it's good to know that it works differently.